# Couldn't match expected type 'x' with actual type `([Char], [Char], [Char])'

Tags: haskell

I have created a data type that is to store information about a group of people: their names and date of birth. The data type is simply two lists of 3-tuples, the first list holds names `(first, middle, last)` and the second holds DOB (Day, Month, Year). You can see the data type below (I've omitted the DOB type because it's irrelevant to this question):

```
data Names = Names [(String, String, String)]
data People = People Names
```

I'm trying to write a function that creates the initial list, so it returns the name of the first person and then the list of `People`. Here it is so far:

```
initiallist :: ([String], People)
initiallist = (first_name, all_people)
    where first_name = "Bob" : "Alice" : "George" : []
        all_people = People ("Bob","Alice","George") : []
```

This results in

```
error:
* Couldn't match expected type `Names'
     with actual type `([Char], [Char], [Char])'
* In the first argument of `People', namely `("Bob", "Alice", "George")'
  In the first argument of `(:)', namely
    `People ("Bob", "Alice", "George")'
  In the expression: People ("Bob", "Alice", "George") : []
```

Now, in my knowledge of Haskell, I thought that `String` is just a `[Char]`. So I figured my code would work fine, but it has me absolutely stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

First one is, `People` data type accepts a `Names` data type but you are trying to feed it with a `[(String,String,String)]` data type.

Second is, as mentioned in @Koterpillar's answer the precedence of the value constructor (here `People` and/or `Names`) are higher than the list value constructor `:` (left association).

Another point is your data types can be defined by `newtype` yielding a more efficient code.

So by keeping in mind that the value constructors are also functions, if you wanted to use the `:` constructor to create your lists  you may as well do like;

```
newtype Names  = Names [(String, String, String)]
newtype People = People Names

initiallist :: ([String], People)
initiallist = (first_name, all_people)
    where first_name = "Bob" : "Alice" : "George" : []
          all_people = People $ Names $ ("Bob","Alice","George") : []
```

or of course you may preferably do like

```
all_people = People (Names [("Bob","Alice","George")])
```

Answer (score 3):

The `:` operator has lower priority than applying the `People` constructor. So your expression is actually:

```
all_people = (People ("Bob","Alice","George")) : []
```

It is indicated in the error message, saying what did `People` constructor apply to:

```
...first argument of `People', namely `("Bob", "Alice", "George")'
```

You will have to make it explicit:

```
all_people = People (("Bob","Alice","George")) : [])
```

Or, with the list notation:

```
all_people = People [("Bob","Alice","George")]
```